# Getting ID of button element with name or class

Tags: jquery

Can i do that ?

```
     var gender = $('.ImdbAddArtist').click(function() {
  alert(this.id);
});
```

I use below code, but it s a little bit strange.

Can i have button's ids from their name?

Comment: Have you tried it? It should work fine.

Comment: Yes. You can query with $("[name=YourElementName]") ..

Comment: Did you even try this?  It works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Your code will work fine:

```
//Bind click event handler to all elements with class of 'ImdbAddArtist'
var gender = $('.ImdbAddArtist').click(function() {
    /* When clicked, alert the value of the 'id' property of 'this'.
    'this' refers to the element that was clicked. */
    alert(this.id);
});
```

As long as the clicked element has an `id` attribute, you will get an alert showing that value. If it doesn't have an `id` attribute, you will get a blank alert.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/K2dDu/).

Answer (score 1):

`$('.ImdbAddArtist')`.  This selects <strike>an element</strike> multiple elements.

Once those elements are selected, you can do whatever you want with them.

If an element has an id, you can get that id, it doesn't matter how it was selected.

Comment: Strictly speaking it selects no, one or many elements, since it's a class selector.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: True, let me fix that.

Comment: $('ImdbAddArtist').attr("id"); gives me undefined :S

Comment: @MertMetin: Your selector should be `$('.ImdbAddArtist')`, you missed the `.`.  Note: that `$('.ImdbAddArtist')` will select ALL elements with that class, `.attr` will get you the info about the 1st one.

Answer (score 1):

your code works fine but i would like to go for [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method to get element attribute...

for id of element `alert($(this).attr("id"));`

for class of element `alert($(this).attr("class"));`

just use .attr() function of jquery will get the id of element

Comment: Why add in the extra burden of calling jQuery again, and then calling a jQuery method, when you can just access the property directly on the element?

Comment: @JamesAllardice Because more jQuery is always better!

Comment: which element i did not define